# Autodesk forge configurator inventor add new model authorization error

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Hello we are using Autodesk [forge configurator inventor](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor) And we created our own js function. Below, you will find the logic we want to import to the application. On it's own, we make it work, but with forge configurator inventor, we get the authentication error. We tried a lot of different options but failed to make it load the document.
Error is --> GET  401 (Unauthorized)

```
import repo from '../../Repository';
var options = repo.hasAccessToken() ?
    { accessToken: repo.getAccessToken() } :
    { env: 'Local' };

var documentId = 'urn:MyUrn';
                Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
                    documentId, (doc) => {
                    console.log("test");
                    let items = doc.getRoot().search(
                        {
                            type: "geometry",
                            role: "3d",
                        },
                        true
                    );
                    if (items.length === 0) {
                        console.error("Document contains no viewables.");
                        return;
                    }
              
                    viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, items[0], {
                            keepCurrentModels: true,
                            //placementTransform: tr,

                        })
                        .then(function (model2) {
                            secondModel = model2;

                            let tr = secondModel.getPlacementTransform();
                            let _selecterTr = _selectedModel.getPlacementTransform();
                            console.log(_selecterTr);
                            tr = _selecterTr;
                            secondModel.setPlacementTransform(tr);
                            viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, true);

                        });
                }, onDocumentLoadFailure,options);

                function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
                    console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that **repo** does not provide an **access token** because it was never needed. The models' **SVF** contents are always loaded directly from the server - instead of relying on the **Model Derivative** service to provide them.

You just have to provide an **endpoint** (e.g. /api/viewables/token) on the **server-side** by adding a **Controller** that could be called from the **client-side** in order to get an **access token** with **viewables:read** scope.

Detailed information here:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/drag-and-drop-design-automation-inventor-sample